# Modify network adapter index on windows7/windows10

Tags: windows, powershell, networking

I currently looking for a way to modify network adapter index on windows operating system.

You can get list of network adapter index on your machine with following command:
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a scripting issue / failure.

These are assigned automatically by the OS when you physically / virtually add adapters to a host and MS will tell you they cannot be changed as discussed here:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/949d8f29-cd33-4053-8a88-33e340a5ceae/changing-network-adapter-interfaceindex